How to Add Google Code Style in CLion When Not Available in Set From List?
Body:
I am using CLion for my C++ development, and I want to configure my code style to follow the Google C++ Style Guide. However, when I navigate to Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | C/C++ and click on Set From..., I do not see an option for "Google" in the list.
Is there a way to manually add or import the Google code style into CLion, or is there an alternative method to achieve this?


In 2024.1 version, if you want to use the predefined code styles, you need to disable the "Use the ReSharper C++ language engine (CLion Nova)" checkbox in File | Settings | Advanced Settings.

Thank you, it works. But why I have to off new fast language engine to use google code style?.. It's really strange for me

Your CLion version looks outdated. My latest version gives me these and lots more. I guess the old versions only have languages. JetBrains adds a lot of stuff. 
